# Spring Data Jpa - Repository doesn't thrown exception when @transactional exists

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following classes:

```
public interface GarageRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Garage, Integer> {}

public class GarageBO {
  private GarageRepository garageRepository;

  public void updateGarage(Garage garage) {
    try {
      garageRepository.save(garage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw BoozinaExceptions.getCodeException(garage, e);
    }
  }
}

public class GarageFacade implements GarageService {
  private GarageBO garageBO;

  @Transactional
  public void updateGarage(Garage garage) {
    garageBO.updateGarage(garage);
  }
}
```

Supposing that i'm trying to update a garage and an unique violation is throwed.
When i call updateGarage from GarageFacade with the `@Transactional` annotation, garageRepository doesn't throws any exception.
When i call the same method without the `@Transactional` annotation, garageRepository throws the unique violation exception and now i can convert the exception using `BoozinaExceptions.getCodeException(garage, e)`;

This behavior happens because when i have the `@Transactional` annotation, the exception will be throwed when Spring jpa data execute the commit. This happens after GarageBO.updateGarage execution ok ?

But i need to convert the unique violation. How can i do that ?
How to handle spring exception after commit then convert to my exception ?

Comment: When the garage entity doesn't exists and i try to save it, the catch block is executed and i can convert the exception. But when the garage entity already exists, the catch block is not executed and this line appears in hibernate log: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is the expected behavior. The transaction is committed after the method ends, the commit leads to the unique constraint violation.

Adding `@Transactional` to the service methods makes the transaction end after the call to the service method the transaction is committed. Removing it makes the transaction commit after the call to the repository method.

Also why do you have a BO a Facade and a Repository?! Basically the BO and Facade are the same IMHO.

TO fix your your problem have your `GarageRepository` extend `JpaRepository` instead of `PagingAndSortingRepository` and call the `saveAndFlush` method instead of `save`. This will execute the sql (not committing the transaction) and trigger a constraint violation exception.

Another solution is to instead of doing a try/catch in your BO create and Aspect which does the conversion. Saves you coding the try/catch each time you need it.

Comment: I have a BO and Facabe because a facade can interact with more than one BO entity.
Example: GarageFacade has a GarageBO and MessageBO because when i create a Garage, i create the entity Garage and send an Email with MessageBO. But i can also create a Garage without send email or i can send email without create Garage.